# Sum of Hour and Time value in diffrent column in excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010

I have an Excel file which contains two columns for hours and minutes, like:

```
hr |min
---+---
 7 |  2
10 | 16
 9 | 12
```

I would like it to present in additional column as

```
07:02
10:16
09:12
```

How to do that in Excel 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    A         B      C
1   hr       min  hr:min
2   1          2
3   2         12
4   3         15
5   10        45
```

click on the cell C2 and put follwing formula at the formula bar and drag it for other rows.

```
=CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(IF(A2 >9, A2, CONCATENATE("0",A2)),":"),CONCATENATE(IF(B2 >9, B2, CONCATENATE("0",B2))))
```

To get Sum of the of hr:min column
click on the cell where you want to display total and put follwing formula at the formula bar.

```
=CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE((SUM(A2:A5) + INT(SUM(B2:B5)/60)),":"),MOD(SUM(B2:B5),60))
```

Comment: Hello Vijendra, this formula works to bring in required format, but it doenst allow me to sum all and get total of all hours and mins.

Comment: you want to sum after bringing them in required format,you didn't write that in the question.

Comment: just go through the answer again, I have write a formula to sum these values.

Comment: Vijendra, i am sorry to bother you again, with first formula, it brought value as hr:min in column C.. as per example above, it will fill value from C2 to C5, at C6, i am looking for total of hours (above range C2:C5), that is not happening :(

Comment: second formula gives you total hr:min. do you want hours only?

Comment: second formula gives very big numbers (5.0368287037037:10.9775578703704),   its not look like HR:MIN format..  i have tried all possible formats plus searched on net..  i have image but i dont know how to attach it with comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
=SUM(TIME(A2,B2,0))
```